# React Native: Component Exception - Objects are not valid as a React child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using [react-native-autocomplete-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-autocomplete-input) to search and show list of addresses.

However upon searching I am getting '**Component Exception - Objects are not valid as a React child...**' error.

When I `console.log` it shows the object results (list of addresses) but it fails to render it. Any help regarding this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I have provided my code snippet below along with the screenshot of the error.

***Here's my code snippet:***

```
 import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    StyleSheet,
    View,
    Text,
    FlatList,
    TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';
import Config from '../config';
import Autocomplete from 'react-native-autocomplete-input';
import _debounce from 'lodash/debounce';

export default class AddAddressSearch extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            form: {
                address: '',
            },

            location: [],
            query: '',
        };

        this.onChangeLocationDebounce = _debounce(this.onChangeLocation, 200);
    }

    async onChangeLocation(input) {
        const COUNTRY_FORMAT = 'country:my';

        try {
            const result = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=${Config.GOOGLE_API_KEY}&input=${input}&components=${COUNTRY_FORMAT}`);
            const data = await result.json();
            this.setState({ location: data.predictions });
        } catch (err) {
            // console.log("LocationPicker onChangeLocation err: ", err)
        }
    }

    searchLocation() {
        console.log('search result: ', this.state.location) //shows the results
        return (
            <View style={{ zIndex: 1 }}>
                <Autocomplete
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    autoCorrect={false}
                    placeholder={'Search Location Name'}
                    data={this.state.location}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.place_id}
                    defaultValue={this.state.query}
                    onChangeText={(address) => {
                        console.log('typed: ', address)
                        this.onChangeLocationDebounce(address);
                    }}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                        //you can change the view you want to show in suggestion from here
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={async () => {
                                this.setState({
                                    query: item.description,
                                    location: [],

                                    // form: {
                                    //   ...this.state.form,
                                    //   address: item.description,
                                    // }
                                });
                                try {
                                    const result = await fetch(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=${item.place_id}&key=${Config.GOOGLE_API_KEY}`,);
                                    const data = await result.json();

                                    let coordinate = data.result.geometry.location;
                                    let latitude = parseFloat(coordinate.lat).toFixed(8).toString();
                                    let longitude = parseFloat(coordinate.lng).toFixed(8).toString();

                                    this.setState({
                                        form: {
                                            ...this.state.form,
                                            latitude,
                                            longitude,
                                        },
                                    });
                                } catch (err) {
                                    // console.error(err);
                                }
                            }}>
                            <View
                                style={[
                                    styles.row,
                                    {
                                        marginHorizontal: 10,
                                        paddingVertical: 5,
                                        borderBottomWidth: 1,
                                        borderColor: '#e6e6e6',
                                    },
                                ]}>
                                <Text>{item.description}</Text>
                            </View>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    )}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }

    form() {
        return (
            <View style={{ margin: 20 }}>
                <View style={{ marginVertical: 5 }} />
                {this.searchLocation()}
            </View>
        );
    }


    renderView() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView>
                {this.form()}
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <>
                <FlatList
                    ListHeaderComponent={this.renderView()}
                    ListHeaderComponentStyle={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}
                    ListFooterComponentStyle={{ marginHorizontal: 20 }}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
};
```

> I have used the same method on another project and it seems to work as intended on that project. Only on this new project I am facing this issue

***Here's the screenshot of the error:***

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### this error shown because you use last version v5.2 or v5 with code working in v4.2 or min

you need to edit `package.json` with the version in other project or edit your code to last version
[here](https://github.com/mrlaessig/react-native-autocomplete-input#example) the code for latest version, and see snack [here](https://byteburgers.com/autocomplete).

```js
//use flatListProps instead with renderItem, see this example
<Autocomplete
   data={data}
   value={query}
   onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ query: text })}
   flatListProps={{
      keyExtractor: (_, idx) => idx,
      renderItem: ({ item }) => <Text>{item}</Text>,
   }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes I was able to fix the issue after checking their documentation.